Issue with Flutter setState not updating Text widget value
I'm starting to get desperate, I'm not understanding a problem related to state in Flutter. I have the following case:
class Testing extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testing({super.key});

  @override
  State<Testing> createState() => _TestingState();
}

class _TestingState extends State<Testing> {

  String? testingVar = "XXX";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: _buildBody(context));
  }

  void onShowPopup() {
    setState(() {
      testingVar = "Oops";
    });
  }

[...]

Text(testingVar ?? "N/A"),

[...]


At some point, I have onTap:
buildSomething(context):


In buildSomething, I have something like this:
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (state is DoneState) {
        onShowPopup();
    }
});

So far, so good. My onShowPopup from Testing is triggered, executed without error, goes through the setState, but the problem is here: Text(testingVar ?? "N/A"), it never changes the value. It's as if the setState didn't serve for anything.
Any help is welcome.

Provide more code including your build

can you share the part that you use Text(testingVar ?? "N/A"), ?

Can you create a gist and share

Please share the full code which contains (Text(testingVar ?? "N/A"),)
